# Flutter Provider List Variable Changing When it Should Not

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using Flutter Provider to manage state across different screens and I am having an issue with some Provider class list variables. I have a widget that allows users to select/unseselect different options from a list which will add/remove the selected/unselected indices from my provider class list. I am trying to implement a feature that allows for saving and discarding of currently selected options. When I first save or discard the current selected indices everything is perfect, the saved indices are/aren't updated accordingly, but when I try to modify those initial selections, my list of saved choices' indices are updated whenever my list of current choices' indices are updated, before even discarding or saving.

I will only post the related Provider class code as the widget code is a lot but if needed will also post.

```
List<int> _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices = [];
List<int> _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = [];

void updateCurrentSelectedFlavorsIndices(int index) {
    if (_currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.contains(index)) {
      _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.remove(index);
    } else {
      _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices.add(index);
    }
    notifyListeners();
 }
 void discardCurrentFlavors() {
    _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices;
    notifyListeners();
 }

void updateSavedIndices() {
    _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices = _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was not come from the `Provider`. Its a normal behaviour of `List` in dart. You set them with same address.

when you call this :`_currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices`, it means they are now same.

I think you want to set all value from the `savedList` in to the `currentList`.

#### SOLUSITON: Use `List.from()`

```
void discardCurrentFlavors() {
    _currentSelectedFlavorsIndices = List.from(_savedSelectedFlavorsIndices);
    notifyListeners();
 }
```

and

```
void updateSavedIndices() {
    _savedSelectedFlavorsIndices = List.from(_currentSelectedFlavorsIndices);
}
```

I hope this helps.